# I can't convert json string to object in Vue.js and javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js

im trying to convert this json string to object, but i can't, the console this erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>
> ```
> at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
> at Vue$3.buildResults (rolList.js:422)
> at Vue$3.boundFn [as buildResults] (vue.js:141)
> at Vue$3.mounted (rolList.js:418)
> at callHook (vue.js:2768)
> at Vue$3.Vue._mount (vue.js:2630)
> at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:6186)
> at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:8557)
> at Vue$3.Vue._init (vue.js:3389)
> at new Vue$3 (vue.js:3437)
> ```

```
The json string is this:

{"modulos":{"1":{"name":" Usuarios","paginas":{"1":{"name":" Listado Usuarios","facultades":{"1":{"name":" ver"}}}}}}}
```

The java script code is this:

```
  resultsLi = new Vue({
    el: '#result-list',
    data: {
      resultls: "",
      json: []
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.buildResults();
    },
    methods: {
      buildResults: function(event) {
        this.json = JSON.parse(this.resultls);
        console.log(this.resultls);

      }
    },
    watch: {
      resultls: function(val, oldVal){
        this.buildResults();
      }
    },
    delimiters: ['${', '}']
  });
```

Comment: Are you positive it's a JSON string and not an object already? Is `this` what you think it's supposed to be inside the `buildResults` definition? Should you have `this.data.resultls` instead? If `this` is supposed to be your `resultsLi`, then `this.resultls` and `this.json` are both `undefined` as they are a child of the `data` property.

Comment: i had convert the json object whit this code: 

 `code`resultsLi.resultls = JSON.stringify(tempList); `code`

because the vue whatcher not detecting changes in the object when i add elements only if  i convert the json in to json string

Comment: just do a `console.log(typeof this.results)` on the line before you call `JSON.parse()` if the result is 'object', then you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`

Comment: I see the vue.js proxies the `data` object, so `this.resultls` would work. My remaining question then would be whether its value is what you think it is.

Comment: The json string that you post is already an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because on initial load, your `resultls` is an empty string. You can change it to be a blanket empty json so it will parse properly and will be updated in watch.

```
resultsLi = new Vue({
  el: '#result-list',
  data: {
    resultls: "{}",
    json: []
  },
  mounted: function () {
   .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me.  I had it as `resultls=null` and was pulling my hair for a couple of hours.  Once I set it to "{}", things started to work.